# A modal in React keep closing and returning an error when I want to click on a button inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog, popup

I keep having this error when I open the modal:

> Uncaught TypeError: handleClose is not a function
> at HTMLDocument.handleClickOutside

This is the modal:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Modal,
  ModalContent,
  ModalActions,
  PrimaryButton,
  ModalTitle
} from '@thermofisher/react-komodo-design';
import './style.scss';

const CreateListModal = ({ isModalOpen, closeModal }) => {
  return (
    <Modal id="simpleModal" isOpen={isModalOpen} handleClose={closeModal}>
      <ModalTitle handleClose={closeModal} />
      <ModalContent>Contect</ModalContent>
      <ModalActions>
        <PrimaryButton onClick={() => console.log('xxx')}>click</PrimaryButton>
      </ModalActions>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default CreateListModal;
```

and this is the component where the modal is called:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Popover from '@material-ui/core/Popover';
import PopupState, { bindTrigger, bindPopover } from 'material-ui-popup-state';
import CreateListModal from '../CreateListModal';

const PopoverButton = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const openModal = () => setModalOpen(true);
  const closeModal = () => setModalOpen(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-popover">
        {(popupState) => (
          <div className="details-button">
            <Button {...bindTrigger(popupState)}>save</Button>
            <Popover {...bindPopover(popupState)}>
              <Box>
                <Typography onClick={openModal}>create a list</Typography>
                {isModalOpen && (
                  <CreateListModal // <- here is the modal called
                    isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
                    closeModal={closeModal}
                  />
                )}
              </Box>
            </Popover>
          </div>
        )}
      </PopupState>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PopoverButton;
```

When that Typography is clicked, `openModal` is opened. It shows the button inside the modal, the one with 'click'. I want when that button is clicked to log in console 'xxx'.

But what is happening is, the modal is closed and the error message that I put at the beginning appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: handleClose is not a function
> at HTMLDocument.handleClickOutside

In browser it shows the following code snippet (even thought it is not from my code):

```
  64 | useEffect(() => {
  65 |   const handleClickOutside = (event: any) => {
  66 |     if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
> 67 |       handleClose()
     | ^  68 |     }
  69 |   }
  70 |
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: ```<ModalTitle handleClose={closeModal} />``` what is `handleClose`? Shouldn't it be `onClick`?

Comment: @yochanansheinberger I tried like  `<ModalTitle onClick={closeModal} />` and it has the same behavior

Comment: Did you try it in the Modal tag to? And why is your modalTitle empty (only a single tag)?

Comment: I don't understand, can you be more clear, please?

Comment: 1. You have the `handleClose` property in two elements `Modal` and `ModalTitle`. try change them both to `onClick`. 2. Shouldn`t the modalTitle actually contain a title?

Comment: I cannot change them to onClick, this is because `Modal` is a library that I us, here it is the library code: https://pastebin.com/3XA2CkyK 2. I can add a title but still the same problem